# TFS 2015 and Sharepoint integration; TF30063 error

Tags: sharepoint, tfs

Both TFS 2015 and Sharepoint 2013 Foundation are on-premise installations. They are on separate servers. Sharepoint is being configured post TFS installation - although I am not currently updating any existing projects.

Account being used to access the sharepoint site is a full admin on both sharepoint collection as well as TFS too.

TFS Extensions are installed, and configured on the Sharepoint server.

Can successfully create a new TFS 2015 project, and see it create the Sharepoint site - however upon accessing the Sharepoint portal site I see a number of TF30063: You are not authorized to access http://app-p-tfs01:8080/tfs errors.

I note that the collection is not listed on the url; I am looking to use the root web application of the sharepoint site as the root location.

Nothing appearing in Security event logs nor the TFS _oi audit.

Any pointers on where to look next?

[image: Sharepoint Dashboard Screenshot]

Comment: It's worth noting that the Sharepoint integration is largely unnecessary these days -- teams can have customized dashboards that far exceed what's present in Sharepoint. Sharepoint also commonly represents a major pain point when upgrading TFS.

Comment: Yup - we're being asked to set this up by our PM team for linked documentation storage etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussing this with Microsoft Support today, it transpired the account Sharepoint was running under (which oddly is the same as TFS), did not have the relevant access - even though it WAS listed under the relevant Services group.

This was added to the Administrators group and all was well.

Very strange.

Answer (score 1):

The "TF30063" error message indicates that your account doesn't have permission to access TFS. As this blog [described](http://nkdagility.com/tfs-2012-issue-tf30063-you-are-not-authorized-to-access-and-cant-trace-permissions), it is caused when some permissions are denied somewhere because deny takes precedence over any other permission.

So, you can run the [tfssecurity /imx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/TFS/administer/command-line/tfssecurity-cmd?TrackId=eef497513265470298dc422ed7c7f85a) command to check which group the account belongs to. Then check these group one by one to see the required permissions are not denied.

For the reporting service error, seems that the report doesn't run correctly. Firstly, go to the report server and ensure the data source can be connected successfully.

Comment: Hi Vicky, will do - but thought I'd checked all the permissions. The account I am using is both a TFS Admin as well as a SP Farm admin, so should have rights.  Are there any particular locations that this access is likely to be denied on, or is it just likely to be top level? Finally, assume this is the 'users' account context and not the SP service account that is likely to not have access?

Comment: Gone through the groups, and there are no explicit denies at all on the top level Collection Security.  In addition the AT security groups have no explicit denies set.